# IValueConverter not being called for Visibility of a DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that will display columns based on a `CheckBox`.  I know that I will need to create an `IValueConverter` for a `bool` to a `Visibility`.  Problem is that my `BoolToVisualConvertor` is not even being called. Cannot figure out why.  This is what I did:

```
public class BoolToVisualConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null) return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            bool data = (bool)value;
            if (data) return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisualConvertor x:Key="BoolToVisaul" />
</Page.Resources>
```

`CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="True" />
```

`DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData" Binding="{Binding Path=MyData}"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisaul}}" >
```

It has to be something simple that I am missing.  Thanks!

edit:  There was a mistake in the copy paste where I have a `DataGrid` that will display columns based on a `CheckBox`.  I know that I will need to create an `IValueConverter` for a `bool` to a `Visibility`.  Problem is that my `BoolToVisualConvertor` is not even being called. Cannot figure out why.  This is what I did:

```
public class BoolToVisualConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null) return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            bool data = (bool)value;
            if (data) return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisualConvertor x:Key="BoolToVisaul" />
</Page.Resources>
```

`CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="True" />
```

`DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData" Binding="{Binding Path=MyData}"  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisaul}}" />
```

It has to be something simple that I am missing.  Thanks!

**edit:** there was a mistake in the copy and paste,  now reads correctly

**edit 2:** Doing more testing it appears the issue is in the DataGrid.  Created a test TextBlock outside the DataGrid like this;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisaul}}" />
```

That works perfectly.  The thing that really confuses me now is that if I do this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData" Binding="{Binding Path=MyData}"  Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

That works...

Comment: Could it be the typo? `local:BooleanToVisaulConverter` --> `local:BooleanToVisualConverter` ?

Comment: Fixed copy and paste mistake.  It was correct in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it with styles. Try this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData" Binding="{Binding MyData}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisualConvertor}}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisualConvertor}}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```